# Visual Paradigm UML Sequence-Diagram LENGTH (Message SEQUENCE NUMBER)

Tags: uml, visual-paradigm

I have a VERY LONG sequence diagram (about 30 messages) that I'm making on visual paradigm. The the whole diagram wont fit on an A4 size paper. So I'm trying to break it in 2 diagrams place side-by-side.

The problem when I do that is that the numbering of messages is changing i.e. on the new diagram, the numbering depends on where it is placed relatively to the older diagram.

For instance, if I place the message relatively below message 2 of older diagram, the message number of new diagram will be 3. There's got to be a better way.

Any suggestion to deal with that LONG diagram so that I can print it or how
can I deal with the Message SEQUENCE NUMBER to break my diagramm in two half !?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it. Below is a link of visual-paradigm forum
http://forums.visual-paradigm.com/posts/list/291006.html

It says :
- right click on a blank area on the sequence diagram
- select "Sequence Number"
- Uncheck "Automatic Update"   et VOILA !!!

You'll also see many other options to deal with the numbering from there.